# Arithmetic sequence with files

Tags: linux, arithmetic

i  have two files,the first file is written numbers for example 123,and the  second file is the same and i want to sum or divide file_one plus file_Two = 123 + 123 result=246 i want to make arithmetic sequence into files number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the shell to do the arithmetic after having it read the files:

```
$ echo 123 > file1
$ echo 123 > file2
$ printf '%d\n' $(( $(<file1) + $(<file2) ))
246
$ printf '%d\n' $(( $(<file1) / $(<file2) ))
1
```

Alternatively, use `bc`:

```
bc <<< $"$(<file1) + $(<file2)"
bc <<< $"$(<file1) / $(<file2)"
```

here we've given `bc` the job of doing the arithmetic and the shell the job of reading in the contents of the files before handing it to `bc` as input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 123 > file1; echo 234 > file2
$ paste -d+ file1 file2 | bc
357
$ paste -d/ file1 file2 | bc -l
.52564102564102564102
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all you have in those files are numbers with no additional text,
here's a one-liner in perl that will sum all the lines in all the files you give it:

```
perl -ne '$s+=$_;END{print "$s\n"}' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

It works because the `-n` switch tells perl to execute the given code on each line of the given files. Each time the contents of the line are put in the `$_` variable. So `$s+=$_` just keeps a running sum and, at the `END`, we print the value of `$s`.

The same in `awk`:

```
awk '{ s+= $0 } END{print s}' file1 file2 file3 ...
```